# How would I pass a macro to my source file from the header file in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm not sure how to word the question, but I'm making a small library in C and I wanted to have optional #includes for additional features. For example, in library.h :

```
#ifndef __LIBRARY_H__
#define __LIBRARY_H__

int addNumber(int a, int b);

#ifdef __ADDITIONAL_FEATURE__
//Additional feature if __ADDITIONAL_FEATURE__ is defined
int subtractNumber(int a, int b);

#endif

#endif
```

And in library.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "library.h"
int addNumber(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
#ifdef __ADDITIONAL_FEATURE__
int subtractNumber(int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
}
#endif
```

And in a test program I did

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define __ADDITIONAL_FEATURE__
#include "library.h"

int main(void) {
    printf("%d", subtractNumber(1, 2));
}
```

But when I compile it, it says that subtractNumber is an unresolved external symbol. But if I define **ADDITIONAL_FEATURE** in library.c, then it works. So how would I somehow pass the **ADDITIONAL_FEATURE** macro to library.c? Or is there another way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Macros cannot be “passed” to an already-compiled library. They are processed during translation (compilation). To have implement a feature that may or may not be in the library, you must produce multiple versions of the library in separate object and/or library files, and a program would use one version or another by linking with one version or another. (Another alternative is for the feature to be always present in the library but that does or does not perform a desired function based on some switch.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one solution i think is defining macro in command of compilation like this instead of `gcc test.c library.c` use `gcc test.c library.c -D __ADDITIONAL_FEATURE__` and remove define from test.c

Answer (score 0):

To see your problem, reconsider your compilation process:
You compile your library like this:

```
gcc library.c -o library.o #See, you didn't define __ADDITIONAL_FEATURE__?
```

If you would look into the functions in the object files, you see only `addNumber`, as `__ADDITIONAL_FEATURE__` wasn't defined==> The function `subtractNumber` was stripped by the preprocessor.

Then, in your testprogram, you define **ADDITIONAL_FEATURE**, you compile with

```
gcc -o executable test.c library.o
```

You reference `subtractNumber`, but it isn't there, as you didn't compile your library.c with `__ADDITIONAL_FEATURE__`.

So the linking fails.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be to implement a function for both versions. If the additional feature is not requested the function can either do nothing or return an error code or print an error message.

Comment: Hey that's a good idea! I think I'll implement the error code bit :)